# How to Integrate github and Ant migration tool?

Tags: migration-tool, ant, github

I am trying to integrate github with ant migration tool and here is the description of the problem I am facing:

I download code from Github everyday and upload to my server using force IDE by right clicking on the classes and triggers folder in eclipse..I would like to avoid this and let ant take care of this.

So here is what I am trying and the problem I am running into:

Below is my directory structure:

[image]

and here is inside the `src` folder...

```
src/
├── applications
├── classes
├── components
├── documents
├── labels
├── layouts
├── objects
│   ├── CustomObject.object
├── package.xml
├── pages
├── permissionsets
├── profiles
├── staticresources
├── tabs
└── triggers
```

I modified the below section in the `build.xml` file as shown below:

```
<!-- Deploy the unpackaged set of metadata retrieved with retrieveUnpackaged -->
<target name="deployUnpackaged">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="src" rollbackOnError="true"/>
</target>
```

And when I run the command `ant deployUnpackaged` here is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: I think this question can be closed..I was so stupid..I just had to change the path for ant-salesforce.jar in the build.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be a problem with the location of your ant-salesforce.jar file. I always include it in my repos in a lib folder. Take a look at my [example repo](https://github.com/dhoechst/Team-Dev-Force-Dot-Com) for a structure that works.

Then, your command would include the -lib switch

```
ant -lib lib/ant-salesforce.jar deployunpackaged
```

Note, another way to deploy from Github is to use [Andy Fawcett's fancy button](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/09/24/deploy-direct-from-github-to-salesforce/).

Comment: You are correct..I just realized after looking at the error closely..but I have another question..In the above case..Do i need to have a package.xml file inside the src folder or package.xml in the same location as build.xml file??

Comment: package.xml should be in the src folder.

Comment: I am sorry to ask another question here in the comments..Here is my package..xml http://pastebin.com/D9egAcsA and when I run the command `ant deployUnPackaged` It reports all these errors: `objects/Case.object (Case.OwnerId) -- Error: Not in package.xml`    Why is it trying to deploy Case object when it is not specified in the package.xml file

Comment: You need to add that to package.xml. The type is CustomObject. If you ask it as another question, I can post with a real answer and formatting.

Comment: Sure..I will post a new question..Thanks so much!!