# Why is ant trying to deploy components which are not described in the package.xml?

Tags: migration-tool, ant

This is kind of linked to my other question

[How to Integrate github and Ant migration tool?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74157/how-to-integrate-github-and-ant-migration-tool)

Here is my package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>31.0</version>
</Package>
```

Here I did not specify the `CustomObjects` type intentionally because we are always working on the classes and triggers and there will be no changes in the Objects,profiles,permission sets..So I deleted those parts from the package.xml

And when I do the command `ant deployUnpackaged` It is trying to deploy everything to server and reports the below errors:

`objects/Case.object (Case.OwnerId) -- Error: Not in package.xml`

Any idea??

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Did yo get solution to this issue? looks like it still has not been fixed by salesforce. What approach did you use?

Comment: You posted your question as answer. Do you want to post your question as comment to my original question then I can respond to your question.

Comment: Sorry as I did not have enough rep to comment I had to post is as an answer.

Comment: Ok. Actually this is not a bug with the tool but this is how it works. Force migration tool tries to deploy everything that is present in the source or root folder. You can have components listed in the package.xml and not present in the folder with attribute allomissingfiles set to true but you cannot have other way. Solution for this is you can have a task in ant which will move the files you want to deploy to another folder and reference that folder in your deployUnpackaged or whatever target. Hope it is clear!

Comment: can you elaborate more on that? As we have code coming from tfs and I am getting the package.xml configured from force.com IDE. Now everytime the developer changes something and wants to deploy to sandbox how will the ant task work? Based on the package.xml? 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: @javanoob http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118411/how-do-i-create-ant-task-to-copy-required-package-xml-filesto-anotehr-directory
I did ask the question can you answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy a folder, Ant is expecting the contents of src to be all listed in the package.xml. If it comes across metadata not listed, then it complains. If you don't want to deploy your objects, then you need to remove them from the src folder.

Comment: Is there an option to specify to exclude the folders objects,profiles,permissionsets?

Comment: Nope. I guess you could write a script to move the things you want to another folder and then deploy that one instead? (In your build.xml, you'd change the deployRoot)

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the idea and thanks again for your time