# How do I create ant task to copy required package.xml filesto another directory to deploy?

Tags: force.com, ant, migration-tool, force.com-ide

I am getting a configured package.xml file from force.com IDE and while using the same package.xml file to deploy changes from another folder ANT is checking all the metadata. I know that the tool works like that but how do I create an ant task which copies only required files to another directory?

Comment: Can you try with 'allowMissingFiles=true' on your deploy target? Looks like your situation is different from mine.

Comment: No it is the same as yours, As I am retrieving everything from a target but I only want to deploy some of the components from it which has been described in package.xml. Allowmissingfiles would work when I have described more components in package.xml than my local directory but here the case is opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample piece of code that I wrote and you can extend it further for your needs.

```
  <!-- Create sub folder called classes -->
    <target name="createClassesFolder">
      <mkdir dir="tempFolder/Classes"/>
    </target>


  <!-- Copy contents of classes folder from source folder -->
    <target name="moveClassesFolder" depends="createClassesFolder">
      <copy todir="ClassesRootFolder/Classes">
        <fileset dir="../src/classes"/>
      </copy>
    </target>
```

Here is how it works:

1. To use this code you should have a folder named `tempFolder` already created.
2. When you run the target `createClassesFolder`, it will create a sub folder named `classes`
3. Now run the target `moveClassesFolder` and this will copy all the contents of `classes` folder from your source folder to the tempFolder created in step 1.

Please note how I used `../src/classes` because I am not running these commands from the same directory as src folder but one directory above.

4. You can also similarly create another target to copy package.xml from source folder to the tempFolder.

With all these steps in place, you should be able to just deploy only classes folder and then don't forget to use `allowMissingFiles=true` attribute because we are using the same package.xml but deploying only subset of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So, If I have classes and few other things to deploy I will have to move everything to the temp folder and make it work that way right? As I will have more than one folder at times and different components as well. Is there any other approach you would suggest to retrieve and deploy using tfs and ant migration tool?

Comment: What tool are you using for version control?

Comment: TFS - team foundation server. What I want is retrieve the latest changes by any developer to local directory and deploy it using ANT. But in doing there is an issue of getting the only latest changes to local directory instead of whole project folder. So I was trying it the other way that by configuring package.xml from force.com IDE but that gave me this error:Not in package.xml.

Comment: I never worked on TFS but I get the problem. Do you run any command to get the changes made by other developers into your local system? If the answer is Yes, you can hook a python script or something to do the clean up of folders for you and after that you can just invoke ant deployUnpackaged target. Let me know.

Comment: No no command yet. They get everything from the eclipse IDE tfs plug in and put it in a local directory so I was figuring out a way to deploy the only component the developer wants.

Comment: That means you have eclipse with TFS plug-in installed and then you would choose some option from that plugin to get changes from other developers right??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38549/discussion-between-apple123-and-javanoob).

Comment: Hi @javanoob is it possible to extend this script to only get files which was last modified in src folder and paste it to the destination folder? Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you so much.

Comment: The way git works is, if we want to get the changes from other developers, we don't need to know the filenames which were changed, we can just run the command `git pull origin master` and it would retrieve only the files that were changed by other developers. If TFS doesn't work this way and pulls the complete src folder from repository irrespective of which file was changed by other developers, then you deploy the complete src folder as long as the complete folder size is less than 50 MB.

Comment: I wrote an ANT script which is copying latest modified files from the tfs local server and pasting it to a temp. Now while doing this I could get the .xml files of the same files together. i am asking another question for this. If you hav idea please answer that. Thank you so much.